# How can I remove Named Color Set in Xcode completely?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I used named a color set at first and recently I removed it from my assets file. (Due to the lack of support of iOS 10)

But it seems they still exist in my project.

If I set a color with same value as the removed named color in Interface Builder, it notices me the named color is missing.

Does anyone have some solution for this kind of case?

Thanks!

Comment: clear them from the build settings in resources and also from derived data and check if it gives the same error.

Comment: Go to Product and select clean...if it's not removed close Xcode and reopen it...

Comment: @SahebRoy The build setting is clean. It's weird, some are removed completely and some are not.

Comment: I just came across this in Xcode 13: The color doesn't show up in "Assets.xcassets" but there's an entry for it in the regular color dropdown list ("MyColor (Missing)") and it's also in the storyboard's source code. Weird they still haven't fixed this.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this for a while and there seems to be no easy way to delete a `namedColour` in XCode (yet). Here's how I solved it.

1. Go to your storyboard and open it as XML.
2. Scroll down the bottom of the document to see a `resources` tag.
3. Inside of that, you should see custom resources like `images` and `namedColour`. Simply just delete any `namedColor` elements that you don't want anymore, and save - you're good to go!

[image]

**Note:** You may also want to search in the XML for any references to that `namedColor` and delete tag. For example, I would search in my XML for `name="Color"` and delete any tag that has it.

Answer (score 1):

I inherited a project that used named colors where we wanted to support iOS 10. You won't like this answer but the only way I found to fix it was to go into the xml of the storyboard and do a `find/replace` on all of my named colors.

You can easily see the xml of the storyboard if you open the Version Editor in the upper right of the project navigator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a (very annoying) bug in Xcode. Here's how you can fix it:

1. Open the color dropdown and click on **Other...**

   [image: Other... option in the dropdown]
2. Navigate to **Color Sliders** (the second icon from the left).

   [image: Color Sliders selected]
3. Select **RGB Sliders** from the dropdown.

   [image: RGB Sliders selected from the dropdown]
4. Click inside the **Hex Color #** text field and press Enter.

   [image: "Hex Color #" text field in focus]

Comment: lol what. This does not work, nor did I expect it to work.

Comment: @Eric It might not work in Xcode 12, but at the time, it definitely worked

Comment: Well it's definitely an interesting solution if it use to work!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this in Xcode 13:

The color doesn't show up in `Assets.xcassets` but there's an entry in the regular color drop-down menu in the inspector and it's marked as "(Missing)":

[image]

This happens if there's a UI element that's still using a color that was deleted.

How to remove the missing color without changing the actual storyboard code manually:

1. Open the storyboard as source code (right-click -> "Open As") and search for the exact name of the color (without "missing"), in my example that would be "HIghlightColor".
2. Write down what UI elements are still using the color - it's easiest to just copy their ids.
3. Open the storyboard again but this time as "Interface Builder - Storyboard".
4. Go through all of the UI elements that are still using the missing color (you can use the id in the search/Find Navigator!) and change their color to something else.
5. Repeat step 1-4 for the remaining storyboards.
6. Once the missing color isn't used by anything anymore, it'll vanish from the list and the storyboards' code automatically, including the entry in the `<Resources>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the Asset Catalog in your project:

[AssetCatalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AFpi.png)

This will delete the missing name, this works for me.